# Unity3D WebGL build не отображает кириллицу

Tags: unity3d, webgl

При запуске из редактора все ок. Однако получившийся билд теряет возможность рендерить кириллицу. Вместо этого выводятся просто пустые строки.
Из того, что удалось нагуглить была проверена кодировка .cs файлов, все utf-8. Был на всякий случай поставлен другой шрифт, хотя и стандартный поддерживает символы кириллицы. А так же в проект были пролинкованы International dll'ки, которые используются для редактора (там то все в порядке). Ничего из этого, к сожалению, не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя ошибка. Проблема была в том, что собственные шрифты нужно устанавливать только в OnGUI, иначе ничего не изменится.